# Wavesurfer.js with WAAPISim fallback not working

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I was using [Wavesurfer.js](http://www.wavesurfer.fm/) with [ELAN annotations](http://www.wavesurfer.fm/example/elan/?scroll) to show the lyrics of a song (along with its Guitar chords). While it is working on the latest versions of Firefox and Chrome, it doesn't seem to support much of others (like IE and older versions of Firefox).

Site link: http://www.naadanchords.com/labs/

There doesn't seem to be a fallback for older browsers which don't support WebAudio. It shows the error: wavesurfer.js: your browser doesn't support WebAudio

I tried using [WAAPISim](https://github.com/g200kg/WAAPISim) Web Audio API Simulator to support browsers that don't support WebAudio. Now I don't see any error in the console, but the waveform is not appearing and I am still not able to hear the audio. Below is a screenshot of the page as rendered in IE11.

[image: Screenshot taken from IE 11]

I want the annotations to support maximum number of browsers before releasing it. Any help appreciated. :)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem. Seems like WAAPISim only supports decoding WAV-files. From their readme:

> createBuffer from ArrayBuffer and decodeAudioData supports only wav
>   format.

Comment: Yeah I tried that. Stack Overflow will allow me to do that only tomorrow.